# How to get schema mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I tried to get the schema from a mongo base but I can only get the schema from a single record. How do I get the schema of all records?

```
var schemaObj = db.getCollection("dado").find({})

function printSchema(obj, indent) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] != "function") {     //we don't want to print functions
        print(indent, key, typeof obj[key]);
        if (typeof obj[key] == "object") {             //if current property is of object type, print its sub properties too
            printSchema(obj[key], indent + "\t");
        }
    }
  }
};

printSchema(schemaObj, "");
```

The result is similar to this, but this only works for one record, I would like to do the same for all.

The actual result query:

```
_id object
   str string
   isObjectId boolean
name string
email string
adress object
   street string
   number number
   district string
   postal_code string
   complement string
   reference_point string
_id object
   str string
   isObjectId boolean
name string
email string
adress object
   street string
   number number
   district string
   postal_code string
   complement string
document string
```

Expected Result:

```
_id object
  str string
  isObjectId boolean
name string
email string
address object
  district string
  postal_number string
  complement string
  number integer
  street string
  reference_point string
document string
```

Comment: how may docs are there in dado collection

Comment: Is it a question or statement?

Comment: The objective is to send the expected result to a relational database, such as SQL for example. I know there are other ways to do this, but I'd like to do it this way. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `compass`, you can use it get `schema` from `analysed sample`

[Reference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/compass/current/schema/export/)

> When Compass analyzes your schema, it samples a random subset of documents from your collection. To learn more about sampling, see Sampling.

Comment: I tested it, but the columns came with the data and I wanted a way in which it was not possible to visualize the data

Comment: Can you elaborate the steps tried?

Comment: I updated the question, could you take a look